# do I need to take care of memory management when using Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using `Picasso` to load tons of (relatively small) images inside a `BaseAdapter` combined with my own implementation of an endless `ListView`. Basically I'm using almost the simplest setup possible:

```
         Picasso.with(c)
            .load(friend.getPhoto_url_200())
            .resize(200, 200)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile)
            .error(R.drawable.default_profile)
            .transform(transformation)
            .into(holder.imgAva);
```

AFAIK, `Picasso` takes care of image caching and recycling on its own. Looking at the logs I see that the amount of memory being freed by GC continuously increases when loading more items (though the amount of RAM used by the application only increases by <3MB when comparing 10 vs 500 loaded items):

```
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 481K, 8% free 23093K/24944K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 348K, 7% free 23399K/25104K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 798K, 8% free 23587K/25532K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 415K, 7% free 24053K/25852K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1761K, 9% free 24153K/26428K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 664K, 9% free 24297K/26428K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 354K, 7% free 25064K/26860K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1064K, 9% free 25568K/27840K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1581K, 10% free 25732K/28480K, paused 22ms, total 26ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1202K, 9% free 26343K/28780K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1514K, 10% free 26537K/29448K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1265K, 10% free 26849K/29768K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1243K, 10% free 27381K/30172K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1615K, 10% free 27956K/30972K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1595K, 10% free 28555K/31588K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2071K, 11% free 29106K/32532K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1879K, 10% free 29837K/33052K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2012K, 11% free 30596K/34132K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2570K, 11% free 31431K/35204K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3169K, 12% free 32091K/36276K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
```

At some point I'm also getting a `JIT` message telling me it's resizing the JIT table to allocate more memory.

In this regard, my questions are:

- Can I do anything to further optimize the process or should I leave Picasso handle it on its own?
- I did not have the opportunity to test this on a low-end device, the Nexus 5 is a relatively powerful device so I wasn't able to reach the heap limit. How would Picasso behave when it starts running out of memory? Will it delete cached items/decrease the amount of images set into the list `ImageViews`/do something else or will it just throw an `OutOfMemoryError`?
- are there any general tips that should be considered when using Picasso to load images into a `ListView`?

Comment: Once I had a similar situation, where I have to load resize the big images and show them in 100x100 in listview. But I was getting the `OutOfMemoryException`. But When I used Picasso, all heap errors gone :D

Answer (score 1):

Using picasso is a very good choice it handles Disk and memory caching with various expiration policies Images downsampling to the target view size to improve performance and reduce memory usage Batching UI updates to improve UI responsiveness So you normally don't have to worry about memory, but i suggestyou give a shot to the volley lib it's far more better

Comment: I use volley primarily for networking operations, are you sure? Because Picasso was intended so be an image loader while volley is a general networking library

Comment: Yes i'm sure about it use volley for loading and cashing your images and more check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: I'm familiar with this tutorial. Well, using Volley u need to manually implement the cache and also take care of things like rounding the image corners, while using Picasso allows use to apply a transformation easily

Comment: I invite you to this link http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/